# Does IIS allow a remote user to list an images folder?

Tags: iis, iis-8

So let's say I have a web app live in IIS and this web app has 100 images in a sub-folder called "/images".

Would IIS allow a remote user to perform a list on this folder, to see the file names of all 100 images?

I wasn't sure if there is any built-in security like this or not.

Environment: IIS 8

Comment: 1) Do users have to log in to use the site? 2) Is directory browsing disabled anyway: [Disable Directory Browsing in IIS 7](http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00756/0/Disable-Directory-Browsing-in-IIS-7.html)? 3) Could a user guess the filenames anyway, and if so would that be a problem?

Comment: Thank you Andrew, your comment resolved my question